# How to set install sample data during Magento 2 installation trough CLI?

Tags: sample-data

I am installing magento2 in a LEMP stack, trough composer and command line.

Follow is the code I am using to install:

```
bin/magento setup:install 
--backend-frontname="adminlogin" \    
--db-host="localhost" \
--db-name="magentodb" \
--db-user="magentouser" \
--db-password="magentouser@" \
--language="en_US" \
--currency="USD" \
--timezone="America/New_York" \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--use-secure=0 \
--base-url="http://www.newmagento.com" \
--base-url-secure="https://www.newmagento.com" \
--admin-user=adminuser \
--admin-password=admin123@ \
--admin-email=admin@newmagento.com \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=user \
--cleanup-database
```

Is there any parameter to force magento to install sample data?

Answer (score 0):

After your Magento installation in order to install sample data using the command line, enter the following command as the Magento file system owner:

`php <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento sampledata:deploy`

*Source: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/sample-data-before-composer.html*

Comment: that should be done after initial instalation?

Comment: yes after initial instalation